# PHP - read text from image with TesseractOCR

Tags: php, tesseract, image-text

I'm using Windows Server 2016 64bit and installed TesseractOCR from here: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki the 64bit version tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20191030.exe

Then I installed the PHP Package: `composer require thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr`

then included this first:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
```

then tried the official way:

```
echo (new TesseractOCR('read.png'))
    ->run();
```

which gave me `500 error`

so I guess it's for old PHP versions (mine is 7) so I looked up and found:

```
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('read.png');
$text = $tesseract->recognize();
file_put_contents('soo.txt', $text);
```

`soo.txt` is geneated but empty

then I tried:

```
$ocr = new TesseractOCR("read.png");
$content = $ocr->run();
echo $content;
```

and this gave me `500 error` again!

what's wrong with it??

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in top off your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

assuming you are not working in a live enviroment.
This will show you details of the error and might give a hint what is wrong.
If this is a live enviroment check the error logs.
500 error doesn't tell anyone a lot.

There is a good chance tessarect wasn't installed (correctly) on your server as this class depents on it, it will show an error.
But thats just a wild guess without any error descriptions.